# Explain Array[Counter]

Tags: java, arrays

This relates to lines 15 and 16 of Fig. 7.2 in Java How to Program, Ninth Edition by Paul Deitel.
I'm just beginning to learn Java. Can someone explain why the **array[counter]** output is zero for the Value column? I understand that the default value for each element in array is zero but I don't quite understand what **array[counter]** is doing. Is the element's default value of zero being multiplied by the counter value 0-9 through each iteration of the loop, which results in zero? Thanks.

```
public class InitArray
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] array; // declare array named array

        array = new int[10]; // create the array object

        System.out.printf("%s%8s\n", "Index", "Value"); //column headings

        // output each array element's value
        for(int counter = 0; counter <array.length; counter++)
            System.out.printf("%5d%8d\n", counter, array[counter]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `array[counter]` corresponds to the element at position `counter` in the array.

Comment: @user3477950 While harsh, that is correct. These are fundamental language concepts and it's difficult to answer them (i.e; we'll probably just repeat what you've read already). Perhaps look over how a for loop works again, then look at arrays, then look at how we can iterate over an array using a for loop and a counter.

Answer (score 0):

This give you the element at position "Counter" in the array. If Counter is Zero you get the first result, because an array in java is Zero based. That meens that the first element in an array has the index zero.

Answer (score 0):

### I am disappointed with the down votes and harsh comments  on this simple question, can't we just simply try and make the concept clear to the user

This is a simple for loop the index of the first element in the array is 0. So when the counter = 0 i.e first element, counter less than the length of the array i.e

```
counter<array.length , print "%5d%8d\n",
```

counter, array[counter] then increment counter i.e counter ++ so the value of counter is increasing which also moves the index of the array.
Hope this Helps.